# Flutter/Dart: Not able to refresh RefreshIndicator data on screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to reload data from DB with RefreshIndicator. Upon over-scroll, Able to read data from DB but somehow not able to refresh the data on the screen. Did i miss/mess up anything?

```
 Future<void> getMTMavailableamount1() async {
    final temp = ModelsPositions().getMasterPositions();
    setState() {
      _futureList = temp;
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Master Control'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: getMTMavailableamount1,
          child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
            future: _futureList,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<dynamic> positions = snapshot.data ?? [];
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: positions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String custID = positions[index][0];
                    String custName = positions[index][1];
                    double m2m = double.parse(positions[index][2]);
                    double available = double.parse(positions[index][3]);
```

Comment: `FutureBuilder` won't work on this case

Comment: Data being loaded from DB in both cases (initial load and upon refresh). If FutureBuilder is not suitable here, any alternatives?

Comment: We can use key to do force rebuild, I added the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce new variable called `uniqueKey` and that should be `ValueKey` with the value of future.

```
late ValueKey<Future> uniqueKey;
Future<void> getMTMavailableamount1() async {
    final temp = ModelsPositions().getMasterPositions();
    setState(() {
      _futureList = temp;
      uniqueKey = ValueKey(_futureList);
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Master Control'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: getMTMavailableamount1,
          child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
            future: _futureList,
            key: uniqueKey,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<dynamic> positions = snapshot.data ?? [];
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: positions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String custID = positions[index][0];
                    String custName = positions[index][1];
                    double m2m = double.parse(positions[index][2]);
                    double available = double.parse(positions[index][3]);
```

Make sure you initiated `uniqueKey` at `initState()`.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureList = ModelsPositions().getMasterPositions();
     uniqueKey = ValueKey<Future>(_futureList);
  }
```

**Edited**

You misused `setState`. your code creates a new inline function instead of calling `setState` of `State`. `setState` looks like as following.

```
setState(() {
      _futureList = temp;
      uniqueKey = ValueKey(_futureList);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Alex Sunder. I tried this way but no luck, Is this correct way to initialize?

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ValueKey<Future> uniqueKey = ValueKey<Future>(Future.value());
    _futureList = ModelsPositions().getMasterPositions();
  }

Comment: I added the `initState` code in my answer

Comment: no luck, still data is not refreshed.

Comment: Can you add your full code after my changes applied.

Comment: I have added full code, please have a look

Comment: I updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: you are awesome @Alex Sunder Singh

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:e2/pages/authorize.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:e2/Models/model_positions.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MasterControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const MasterControl({super.key});

  @override
  State<MasterControl> createState() => _MasterControlState();
}

class _MasterControlState extends State<MasterControl> {
  List<dynamic> _selectedItems = [];
  //List<MasterPositions> positions = [];
  late Future<List<dynamic>> _futureList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureList = ModelsPositions().getMasterPositions();
    uniqueKey = ValueKey<Future>(_futureList);
  }

  late ValueKey<Future> uniqueKey;
  Future<void> getMTMavailableamount1() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://jhkmmy7zhx2dj2yag74j7p5k2e0fyqnj.lambda-url.ap-south-1.on.aws/'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );
    final temp = ModelsPositions().getMasterPositions();
    setState() {
      _futureList = temp;
      uniqueKey = ValueKey(_futureList);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Master Control'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: getMTMavailableamount1,
          child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
            future: _futureList,
            key: uniqueKey,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<dynamic> positions = snapshot.data ?? [];
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: positions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String custID = positions[index][0];
                    String custName = positions[index][1];
                    double m2m = double.parse(positions[index][2]);
                    double available = double.parse(positions[index][3]);
                    //String symbol = positions[index][4];

                    return Card(
                        child: Row(children: [
                      Checkbox(
                        value: _selectedItems.contains(positions[index]),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (value == null) {
                              return;
                            }
                            if (value) {
                              _selectedItems.add(positions[index]);
                            } else {
                              _selectedItems.removeWhere(
                                  (item) => item == positions[index]);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 2),
                            Text(custID),
                            const SizedBox(height: 2),
                            Text(custName),
                            const SizedBox(height: 2),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        //fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(height: 3),
                            Text(
                              'MTM       : $m2m',
                              softWrap: false,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  color: m2m > 0.0
                                      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 180, 16)
                                      : Colors.red[600]),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              'Available : $available',
                              softWrap: false,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                  color: available > 0.0
                                      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 11, 180, 16)
                                      : Colors.red[600]),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]));
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(
                    child: Text('Failed to fetch Positions Summary'));
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
        ),);
  }
}

class LambdaResponse {
  late int statusCode;
  late String msg;

  LambdaResponse({required this.statusCode, required this.msg});
  
  factory LambdaResponse.fromJson(String response) {
    print('here1');
    print(response);
    return LambdaResponse(
      statusCode: 1,
      msg: response,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).